# Neo4j performance - counting nodes - linked list performance - alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, neo4j, cypher

**UPDATED:  Wes hit a home run here! Thanks.. I've added a Rails version I was developing using the neography Gem.. Accomplishes the same thing but his version is much faster..  see comparison below**

I am using a linked list in Neo4j (1.9, REST, Cypher) to help keep the comments in proper order (Yes I know I can sort on the time etc).

```
(object node)---[:comment]--->(comment)--->(comment)--->(comment).... etc
```

Currently I have 900 comments and it's taking **7** seconds to get through the whole list - ***completely*** unacceptable.. I'm just returning the ID of the node (I know, don't do this, but it's not he point of my post).

What I'm trying to do is find the ID's of users who commented so I can return a count.. (like "Joe and 405 others commented on your post").. Now, I'm not even counting the unique nodes at this point - I'm just returning the author_id for each record.. (I'll worry about counting later - first take care of the basic performance issue).

```
start object=node(15837) match object-[:COMMENTS*]->comments  return comments.author_id
```

7 seconds is waaaay too long..

Instead of using a linked list, I could just simply have an object and link all the comments directly to the node - but that could lead to a supernode that is just bogged down, and then finding the most recent comments, even with skip and limit, will be dog slow..

Will relationship indexes help here?  I've never used them other than to ensure a unique relationship, or to see if a relationship exists, but can I use them in a cypher query to help speed things up?

If not, what else can I do to decrease the time it takes to return the IDs?

**COMPARISON:  Here is the Rails version using "phase II" methods of the Neography gem:**

```
next_node_id=18233
@neo=Neography::Rest.new
start_node = Neography::Node.load(next_node_id, @neo) 
all_nodes=start_node.outgoing(:COMMENTS).depth(10000)
raise all_nodes.size.to_i
```

Result: 526 nodes found in 290ms..

Wes' solution took 5 ms.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationship indexes will not help. I'd suggest using an unmanaged extension and the traversal API--it will be a lot faster than Cypher for this particular query on long lists. This example should get you close:

https://github.com/wfreeman/linkedlistlength

I based it on Mark Needham's example here:
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/07/20/neo4j-2-1-2-finding-where-i-am-in-a-linked-list/

Comment: How would I use this via REST?   I'm not using JRuby - rather plain old  Rails 3.2 and Rest..

Comment: You install it into your neo4j server lib folder, restart, and call it via rest: localhost:7474/linkedlistlength/:nodeid

Comment: Ok.. hate to be a n00b here, but I stopped the server,  copied the folder into my local neo4j lib folder of my rails project, restarted, and I get this: HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /linkedlistlength/:2343. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't exactly ready for your server as is. You've got to first convert it to use 1.9.x to match your version (it's set up for 2.1.4 in the pom.xml). Then you have to `mvn package` and copy the jar file from the target folder to your lib folder.

Comment: Also, the nodeid doesn't need a colon in front of it. And you need to add the following line to your neo4j-server.properties:
`org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.skeweredrook.linkedlistlength=/linkedlistlength`

Comment: changed <version> to 1.9.8 ... mvn failed - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project linkedlistlength: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Volumes/Data/BlueFrog/BigData/n2/neograph/extensions/linkedlistlength-master/src/main/java/com/skeweredrook/linkedlistlength/LinkedListLength.java:[32,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method traversalDescription()
[ERROR] location: interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService

Comment: Sorry, I guess 1.9.8 had a slightly different API for creating a traversal (made a new branch): https://github.com/wfreeman/linkedlistlength/tree/1.9.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61780/discussion-between-ruben-catchme-obregon-and-wes-freeman).

Comment: For some reason the /li‌​nkedlistlength in the server property setting was being read by the server as  [/liâânkedlistlength   I replaced the two ââ with an n and then it worked... 

Thanks for your help.. Before you answered I tried something in rails to get the counts and it worked - updating my question.. Would be interesting to see which one is faster..
(this setting:  org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.skeweredrook.linkedlistlength=/li‌​nkedlistlength )

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing this to return a count, the best solution here is to not figure it out on every query since it isn't changing that often. Cache the results on the node in a `total_comments` property to your node. Every time a relationship is added or removed, update that count. If you want to know whether any of the current user's friends commented on it so you can say, "Joe and 700 others commented on this," you could do a second query:

`start joe=node(15830) object=node(15838) match joe-[:FRIENDS]->friend-[:POSTED_COMMENT]->comment<-[:COMMENTS]-object RETURN friend LIMIT 1`

You limit it to 1 since you only need the name of one friend who commented. If it returns someone, adjust the number of comments displayed by 1, include the user's name. You could do that with JS so it doesn't delay your page load. Sorry if my Cypher is a little off, not used to <2.0 syntax.

Comment: Thanks!  But I already do that for the number of comments - my post is a a bit confusing because I generalized the problem.. What I'm trying to do is count *unique* commenters - I kinda left that part off since I'm just trying to solve the basic performance issue.  When I count the number of comments, not commenters, I do exactly as you explained.. Thanks!

Comment: OH, I see now! You need unique comments to display number of comments, not number of comments. What about caching that on the object node as well? When a comment is added, perform a match to determine whether that user has commented before. If no, increment the count by one? Do the same, lower the count on delete? Or do you need the author ID of each unique commenter every time?

Comment: Hmm.. now that's a thought - I don't need it every time..  I was going to use a relationship index to store the relationship and check to see if it existed.. but even that takes 100ms to create, and then who knows how long to read when saved..  And to add to it, I uses a linked list for each user for their actions.. But, I will try this approach - on a save, check the relationship index to see if they already commented, if not, increment the number of counters..

Comment: Cool, good luck! Be careful with relationship indexes. They don't exist in >= 2.0 and I have to imagine you're going to want to upgrade at some point. You can switch to Elasticsearch but it gets to be a pain.